# Why is character "£" in a string interpreted strange in the command cut?

Tags: command-line, utf-8, cut-command

I'm developing a bash script and came up with the following strange behaviour!

```
$ echo £ |cut -c 1
�
```

The sign `£` is passed to the next command `cut` whose filter is picking one character only.

When I modify the filter in the `cut` command to pick 2 characters, then the `£` is passed through!

```
$ echo £ |cut -c 1-2
£
```

Not a severe problem, I have a workaround solution in the script, but why does the filter in the cut command require 2 positions instead of 1 when picking a `£` sign?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this Unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163721/can-not-use-cut-c-characters-with-utf-8).

Answer (score 44):

The `cut` command in Ubuntu is not multi-byte character aware. [Characters are the same as bytes](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cut.c;h=0f6ba602c207018721414459e0c2df18d15dd190;hb=8d13292a73ecf1f265f77731d3ace29866e3d616#l503)  for this version of the `cut` command.

The pound sign (`£`) is a UTF-8 character that consists of two bytes (`c2` and `a3`):

```
$ echo £ | od -t x1
0000000 c2 a3 0a
0000003
```

*Note*: The `0a` character is the "New Line" (ASCII "Line Feed" character).

When you `cut` the first character from the line, you are selecting only the `c2` part of `£`, and this is not a valid UTF-8 character. As a result you get the strange question mark `�` ([the replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)) on screen:

```
$ echo £ | cut -c 1 | od -t x1
0000000 c2 0a
0000002
```

*Note*: The above was tested with the latest version of `cut` in Ubuntu 20.10 (***GNU coreutils version 8.32***).

If you want to select multi-byte characters, you can use the `grep` (***GNU grep version 3.4***) command like this:

```
$ echo x£β | grep -o '^.'
x
$ echo x£β | grep -o '^..'
x£
$ echo x£β | grep -o '^...'
x£β
```

---

<sub>This answer was improved with the help of the comments.</sub>

Comment: _"The `cut` command is not multi-byte character aware."_ - Interestingly, (GNU) cut has both options for selecting bytes (`-b`), and for selecting characters (`-c`). One would hope it would know how to deal with multi-byte characters then...

Comment: You might want to change `echo` to `echo -n` in your first example, so that there's no extra `0a`

Comment: Initially I did that way @GrzegorzOledzki . However, since  the second example with `cut` had it already,  I removed the `-n` in the first example, for consistency.

Comment: @marcelm Some `cut`s do actually make a distinction between `-b` and `-c`. My `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.32` does the right thing with `-c` in an UTF-8 locale, but it turns out that it's due to a downstream Fedora patch. Upstream coreutils still handle `-b` and `-c` as aliases of the same thing at the moment.

Comment: Note, that strange question mark is known in Unicode as the replacement character. It’s officially supposed to be used when a character or byte cannot be translated to a Unicode code point in the currently selected encoding (and in some cases it may also be used to represent characters that the current font does not include glyphs for).

Comment: @marcelm, [`cut` is specified to have both `-b` and `-c`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cut.html). The GNU implementation [just treats them as identical](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cut.c;h=0f6ba602c207018721414459e0c2df18d15dd190;hb=8d13292a73ecf1f265f77731d3ace29866e3d616#l503)...

Answer (score 20):

In UTF-8 encoding, the hex value of `£` is `0xC2 0xA3 (c2a3)` which is `11000010 10100011` in binary.

So it's two bytes (like two character). `cut -c` considers each byte a character which produces `�`.

---

```bsh
$ echo -n £ | xxd
00000000: c2a3                                     ..

$ echo -n £ | wc --bytes
2
```

Comment: Characters starting from U+0080 (Latin-1 Supplement) usually show similar behaviour. You can find Unicode table on https://unicode-table.com/

Comment: UTF-8 can have up to 4 bytes, which is not very intuitive. It's a gotcha, as it includes 7-bit ASCII but extends it.

Comment: Curiously, `echo -n £ | wc --char` returns `1` so wc knows a different definition of char than cut.

Comment: To be clear GNU cut considers each byte to be a character with -c — other versions of cut will treat characters correctly.